# How to get column field only with spring-data-jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How can I make `spring-data-jpa` return a `String` column only, instead of a bean?

The following should return the `bookingNumber` String from a `Booking` `@Entity`:

```
public interface BookingRepository extends CrudRepository<Booking, Long> {
    String findDistinctBookingNumberByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

If the booking exists, I'm getting the following exception instead of the bookingnumber string only:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class Booking cannot be cast to class java.lang.String 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.findDistinctBookingNumberByLastname(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Sidenote: I know I could write a native `@Query` on the interface methods, but I'd prefer a query by method name only.

Comment: I think by now is not possible, as alternatives you have `@Query` (as you mention) and `Projections`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: `spring-data-jpa` is an `ORM framework` ,which meas it focuses on Object or Entity,returning a `string` colume  is not recommended.you could declare a `Booking` return type then retrive the `bookingNumber` field in high-level code